# Get strongly typed objects from without throwing deserialization exception

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, deserialization

I'm using the mongodb c# driver and trying to execute a query against my mongo db:

```
MongoCursor<FooBar> cursor = mongoCollection.FindAs<FooBar>(query);
List<FooBar> list = cursor.ToList();
```

If one of the matching documents in mongo does not match the FooBar object exactly, I get an exception. I would like the deserializer to be a bit more tolerant. Either just give me the objects where the serialization did not fail, or avoid that the serialization fails by ignoring missing fields and properties.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exception are you getting? Possibly a `NullReferenceException`? Use `try catch` blocks and simply ignore the exception inside `catch`?